# Python loop print

Tags: python, loops

I have a dictionary like this:

```
questions ={
    '1.Who is Satoshi Nakamoto' : {'answers':{'right_answer':'Pseudonym','wrong_answer':['Bill Gate', 'Elon Musk', 'Warren Buffet']}},
    '2.Who is richest' : {'answers':{'right_answer':'Pseudonym','wrong_answer':['Bill Gate', 'Elon Musk', 'Warren Buffet']}}

}
```

Based on the dictionary, I want to print the questions and the option values.

This is the code I used:

```
for question in q:
  print(question)
  answers =([questions[question]['answers']['right_answer']] +questions[question]['answers']['wrong_answer'])
  for answer in answers:
    print(answer)
```

This produces a result like:

```
1.Who is Satoshi Nakamoto

Pseudonym

Bill Gate

Elon Musk

Warren Buffet

2.Who is richer
Pseudonym

Bill Gate

Elon Musk

Warren Buffet
```

But I want to print the options with bullet headers A, B, C, D, etc. like this:

```
1.Who is Satoshi Nakamoto

A.Pseudonym

B.Bill Gate

C.Elon Musk

D.Warren Buffet

2.Who is richer
A.Pseudonym

B.Bill Gate

C.Elon Musk

D.Warren Buffet
```

Maybe someone could help me this. Thank you so much!

Comment: What is in `q`?

Comment: What have you done to try and add these labels?

Comment: I think I could find a solution, but the design of the full structure looks wrong.

Comment: Here is a tip, look at the docs for `f-strings`, `enumerate`, `ord`, and `chr` in that order. Practice with each and you can do what you want.

Comment: Simpler: use `zip` and `strings.ascii_uppercase`. (I doubt you have more than 26 answers per question.)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `string` library's ascii uppercase and `zip()` to enumerate your answers:

```
import string

answers = ['Pseudonym', 'Bill Gate', 'Elon Musk', 'Warren Buffet']
for bullet, answer in zip(string.ascii_uppercase, answers):
    print(f"{bullet}. {answer}")
```

`zip()` will take some number of lists (or other collections) and group the first element of each collection, then the second, then the third and so on. So, `zip([1,2,3], ['a','b','c'])` will give you `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]`. Then, your `for` loop unpacks each of these tuples and makes them available for the print statement's f-string.

This produces the following result:

```
>>> answers = ['Pseudonym', 'Bill Gate', 'Elon Musk', 'Warren Buffet']
>>> for bullet, answer in zip(string.ascii_uppercase, answers):
...     print(f"{bullet}. {answer}")
...
A. Pseudonym
B. Bill Gate
C. Elon Musk
D. Warren Buffet
```

Answer (score 1):

I redesigned the structure of `questions` because I don't think it's good. Making `questions` a list allows us to shuffle the questions so that they don't always come in the same order. I shuffled the answers too, so that the correct answer won't always be in the first position.

```
import random
import string

questions = [
    {'question': 'Who is Satoshi Nakamoto',
     'right_answer': 'Pseudonym',
     'wrong_answers': ['Bill Gate', 'Elon Musk', 'Warren Buffet']},
    {'question': 'Who is richest',
     'right_answer': 'Pseudonym',
     'wrong_answers': ['Bill Gates', 'Elon Musk', 'Warren Buffet']}]

random.shuffle(questions)

for i, entry in enumerate(questions, start=1):
    all_answers = entry['wrong_answers'] + [entry['right_answer']]
    random.shuffle(all_answers)
    print(f'{i}. {entry["question"]}')
    for letter, answer in zip(string.ascii_uppercase, all_answers):
        print(f'  {letter}. {answer}')
```

A possible result:

```
1. Who is richest
  A. Pseudonym
  B. Warren Buffet
  C. Bill Gates
  D. Elon Musk
2. Who is Satoshi Nakamoto
  A. Elon Musk
  B. Pseudonym
  C. Warren Buffet
  D. Bill Gate
```